# Intersect errors, memory issues in QGIS

Tags: qgis

my datasets are:

```
Track_02(simple road polyline shp)
***intersected with***
road_cat_cls(polygon for road categorization)
elev_rcls_poly(polygonized classified DEM)
slp_rcls_poly(polygonized classified slope grid)
```

With Arc, you are able to intersect multiple layers, however in QGIS it is limited to 2 at a time?  Also, the more intersects I run (I intersect the previous output with the next polygon layer in line) it takes longer and longer obviously, and when I get to the last, slp_rcls_poly, it is sticking on 4%.  Lastly, after checking the second output, I am seeing that the intersect has not fully worked, as part of my road is missing from that output.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the core of your question? Isn't it more of a feature request/bug report?

Comment: Has the topology been validated?

Comment: The core is whether or not others are also experiencing these issues. 
Yes, topology has been validated and is all valid.

Comment: Is it possible that you are getting lots of tiny geometries after each intersection? Perhaps you are getting too many features to work with. Could you simplify the result with some acceptable tolerance after each intersection?